# google classroom api to create a course using js

Tags: javascript, google-classroom

i am new with google classroom api and i want to create a course on local machine. can i do it or not ?
if create then how using javascript ?
as i try ,got an error with code =>403, status="PERMISSION_DENIED" and message=> "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

in my code i use function createCourse() to create a new course.

my code is below given

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '782126680600-9kkg23inbnn9sv8ficcvjci2rgrnd648.apps.googleusercontent.com';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/classroom/v1/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly";

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          createCourse();
          listCourses();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print the names of the first 10 courses the user has access to. If
       * no courses are found an appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listCourses() {
        gapi.client.classroom.courses.list({
          pageSize: 10
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.info(response.result);
          var courses = response.result.courses;
          appendPre('Courses:');
          if (courses.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
              var course = courses[i];
              appendPre(course.name)
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No courses found.');
          }
        });
      }
        function createCourse(){
            var newCourse = {'name': '9th Math','ownerId' : 'me','courseState' : 'PROVISIONED'};
            gapi.client.classroom.courses.create(newCourse).then(function(response) {
                console.info(response);
            });
        }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

please reply me..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your scope from `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses`.

According to the document, [courses.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create) requires the following OAuth scope:`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses` to work.

The scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly` is used for listing and getting data. If there is a need to create, update you have to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses` to gain full access to the API.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i need another help when i try to get course details like as :             
function getCourse(courseId){
    gapi.client.classroom.courses.get(courseId).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}                                                                                                                   
error msg is => "Required path parameter id is missing."                               the above function is access when we click on link like as              
<button class="btn btn-link btn-sm" onclick="getCourse(7101509957)">12th math</button>

Comment: please se this link=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914125/google-classroom-api-to-get-a-course-details-using-js